# When resume my app, all subviews like rendered twice

Tags: ios

I'm developing on iOS6, and encounter one strange problem.
Sometimes when I pressed home button and wait for a while, resume my app will see all subviews was rendered like twice.
 
When I print the log, find that before `applicationWillEnterForeground`, all subviews' `drawRect` was called, but I don't know who did this.
I check the ViewController life cycle, still can't explain, someone can help? Thanks.

Comment: Where you have used addSubView method?

Comment: @CRDave Yes, I add subviews in my **loadView**.

Comment: You should change the title..

Comment: why not set a breakpoint on one of your subview's "`drawRect`" and see what happens in the Xcode debugger?

Comment: @hfossli sorry, is the title not clear?

Comment: Do you mean that the subviews are created twice (doubled the count of UIView-instances) OR do you mean it is rendered twice? Your text and title seems to mismatch.

Comment: @MichaelDautermann Because this problem not happened everytime, I don't even know how to reproduce it. Once I thought maybe because of low memory, but it seems not like that.

Comment: @hfossli thank you, I have changed the title. Through log, all subviews are not be inited another time, so I think there is only one instance of each UIView.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the OS does a lot of work for you.. If it has to release rendered stuff while in background I'm not supprised. It will then just redraw when ever needed.

You can check if setNeedsLayout and setNeedsDisplay is being called and/or if frame changes.